# Java saving an object by date

Tags: java, exception, object, file-io, io

I am trying to save an object to a file with the class below but it gives me java.io.NotSerializableException.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

class Saver {

  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

  public void save(ArrayList<Product> products) {
    for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
      try { 
        FileOutputStream saveFile = new FileOutputStream(
        "/" + products.get(i) + ".product"
        );

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);
        oos.writeObject(products.get(i));
      } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex); 
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Whereas the class Product looks like this:

```
class Product {

  private String title;
  private int id;
  private double price;

  public Product(String title, int id, double price) {
    this.title = title;
    this.id = id;
    this.price = price;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  } 

  public double getPrice() {
    return price;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
  }

}
```

what am I doing wrong and how can I store the objects in a file then?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the exception says, the class (`Product` in this case) isn't serializable. You can *probably* just get away with this change:

```
class Product implements Serializable {
     // Code as before
}
```

but you should also consider declaring a `serialVersionUID` field for versioning purposes. Read the docs for [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7//docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) and the [serialization tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) for a *lot* more detail. You don't need to write any new members - it's just a marker interface - but there are other methods you can add to give more control over serialization and deserialization.

You should also consider alternative serialization approaches - personally I like [Google Protocol Buffers](http://protobuf.googlecode.com), but I'm biased :) Consider what versioning you'll need, and any cross-platform support.

Additionally:

- You're using `Product.toString()` implicitly in the filename, but that won't give you anything useful. What do you *want* the filename to be based on?
- You're not doing anything with `cal` - how do you want the current date/time to be stored?

Comment: The code looked different first (hence the title with the date) but i thought that this caused the problem so i left that away. I was saving the file with the getTitle() method and wanted to the files in a directory with the date as its name. Thanks for the quick answer, it works! And how can i add the date only for a directory like:
\12252012\product1.product

Comment: @Selim: This is why it's important to take your time writing a question... make sure it's consistent, and that you only include the code and text you need to. Now, it sounds like your second question is really about formatting a date as a string... look into `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Thanks again! This was my first question expect the ones coming to be better :-)

Comment: @Selim: No problem. If you've got the time, you might want to read my guides to asking really good questions: http://tinyurl.com/so-list and http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 5):

You have to serialize your Product class by implementing the [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface which is a marker interface for your class which you want to save the sate of.

```
class Product implements Serializable {
```

[tutorial Link for Object Serialization in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html)